# Undefineted offset 1

Tags: php

I have built a small script to check if '158' is in a string and if it is, output a couple things.

If '158' is not in the string, I keep getting the php notice message:

> Message: Undefined offset: 1

```
$cart_check = '145+0,159+1,197+3,';

$cart_check = trim($cart_check, ',');

$cart_check = explode(',', $cart_check);

$check_entry_id_exists = '';
$key = '0';

if (array_search(158, $cart_check)) {
    $check_entry_id_exists = 'yes';
    $key = array_search(158, $cart_check);
}

$cart_check_row_id = explode("+", $cart_check[$key]);

$cart_check_row_id = $cart_check_row_id[1];
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, can anyone take a look at my code and see:

1. what the reason the notice is displaying.
2. If there is a way to better my script (I am learning and am sure I am not doing things as best as possible).

Thank you

Comment: The error means that there is no second parameter in your array `$cart_check_row_id[1];` <-- the `1` here is causing it. `var_dump` `$cart_check_row_id` and post the results

Comment: make sure you have an empty line somewhere. That's why explode() will return only an empty $key, but have nothing to assign.

Comment: your code works. you are not running the code you posted in your question.

Comment: i have tested your code. it is working perfectly fine evenif there no string for 158.

Comment: I see now it is when 158 is not in the string. How can I check and only run the code id it is?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your (2), a better way would be to look at [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

You could do what you are attempting in 2 lines of code

```
preg_match('/,158\+(\d+)/', $cart_check, $output);
$cart_check_row_id = (empty($output[1])) ? 0 : $output[1];
```

Comment: +1 wouldn't `'/^158\+(\d+)$/'` be better, as 3158+33 would be a match?

Comment: `^` and `$` would tie the match to the start and end of the line, so wouldn't fix your test case (see http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ud), but you could add a `,` to the regex so that it only matches `,158`

Comment: Thank you. I will look at using this.
i DID A var_dump as you asked and the result was : string(1) "0"

Comment: $cart_check = explode(',', $cart_check); would make it an array, so it would. Adding a `,` would need to account for start and end too, so you'd have to use `','.$cart_check.','` as the data

Answer (score 1):

```
$cart_check_row_id = 
    preg_match('@(?:\\A|,)158\\+(\\d++)@', trim($cart_check)) ?
    (int)$matches[1] :
    false
;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have run your code and find this answer for string "145+0,157+1,197+3,".

$cart_check = explode(',', $cart_check);
print_r($cart_check) output as,

Array
(
    [0] => 145+0
    [1] => 157+1
    [2] => 197+3
)

$cart_check_row_id = explode("+", $cart_check[$key]);
print_r($cart_check_row_id); output as :
Array
(
    [0] => 145
    [1] => 0
)

$cart_check_row_id = explode("+", $cart_check[$key]);
print_r($cart_check_row_id); output as,

0